# How do I Pull Wordpress Blog Titles and Dates into a .NET Homepage

Tags: .net, wordpress

i'm trying to pull the title and date into the homepage for the last three wordpress blog posts.  forgive me as i am not versed in .net at all.

in top of my default.aspx page i have this command:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="DefaultNew.aspx.cs" Inherits="_DefaultNew" Debug="false" %>
<%@ Register Src="DefaultWordpress.aspx.cs" TagPrefix="Site" TagName="Wordpress" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/includes/siteHomeHeaderNew.ascx" TagPrefix="Site" TagName="Header" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/includes/siteFooter.ascx" TagPrefix="Site" TagName="Footer" %>
```

Where i want the titles to pull in i have:

```
<Site:Wordpress runat="server" />
```

Then in my DefaultWordpress.aspx.cs file i have this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;

public partial class Wordpress : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://MY_SITE_GOES_HERE.com/blog/index.php?feed=atom"))
    {
        var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        // Print title and summary of 3 most recent posts
        foreach (var post in feed.Items.Take(3))
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("--- {0} ---", post.Title.Text);
            Console.WriteLine (post.Summary.Text);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a Compilation Error that says this:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Source Error:

```
Line 16: public partial class Wordpress : System.Web.UI.Page 
Line 17: {
Line 18:    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.MY_SITE_HERE.com/blog/index.php?feed=atom"))
Line 19:    {
Line 20:        var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

Source File: \\fs3-n02\stor9wc1dfw1\646363\647414\www.MY_SITE_HERE.com\web\content\DefaultWordpress.aspx.cs    Line: 18
```

This is obviously not working but i'm not sure where to go from here.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  is there an easier way to do this, or just something i'm missing?

thank you!!

Comment: What is not working? Any errors, wrong output, etc.

Comment: @Xharze there is a Compilation Error: i'll update the info above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `using` statement in a method,for example `Page_Load` or any other method you would like.
Apart from that you can't use `Console` on a webpage.

Putting the code inside a method could look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://MY_SITE_GOES_HERE.com/blog/index.php?feed=atom"))
  {
    var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    // Print title and summary of 3 most recent posts
    foreach (var post in feed.Items.Take(3))
    {
        // ... Logic to render post information ...
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
You are using .NET 2.0 which doesn't have the `SyndicationFeed` class. You could try to use [Atom.NET](http://atomnet.sourceforge.net/) instead which should support .NET 2.0.

Comment: thanks, again, i really really don't know .net at all, what would that line / statement read exactly? Would it be in something like this? protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

Comment: thanks for all your help, but when i updated that code, i'm now getting this error: "Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @aaronb Which C# version are you using? Only C# 3.0 and above supports the `var` keyword. You could try to replace `var` with `SyndicationFeed`. And the `var` in the `foreach` with `SyndicationItem`.

Comment: looks like it is: Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456 – is it possible to update the code above you pasted?  when i tried your suggestion i got this: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SyndicationFeed' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this the class you are trying to use, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx? If so you have to upgrade the .NET 3.5, as it doesn't exist in earlier versions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11131/discussion-between-aaron-b-and-xharze)